# Checking for null value in c# var with LINQ & Entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, var

I'm quite new to LINQ & Entity framework as well as the var keyword in c# so please pardon me if this sounds like a 'newbie' question.

I have problems checking for null values after doing something like this:

```
var entry = myDB.Entries.Where(e => e.Email == entry.Email);
```

Even when the email does not exist in the database, entry does not equate to null.

So instead of `if (entry == null)` i had to do `if (entry.Count() < 1)` to check for existing Entry before i execute my next batch of statements. Is there any reason why the variable wouldn't be considered null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, `entry` will *never* be `null`. What you think of as `null` is in fact an `IEnumerable<Entry>` with no items.

If you want to check if there is at least one entry with your criteria, you normally do something like:

```
var entries = myDB.Entries.Where(e => e.Email == entry.Email);
if (entries.Any()) {
    // ...
}
```

If you know that there will be *at most* one entry, then you can also do:

```
var entry = myDB.Entries.Where(e => e.Email == entry.Email).SingleOrDefault();
if (entry != null) {
    // ...
}
```

This is closer to what you imagined, but will throw an exception if there is more than one matching entry.

Comment: thanks! great help and insight as i forgot that i was using DBContext to check for entries.

Comment: You could append .SingleOrDefault() to the query to get one result or null as well.

Answer (score 0):

"var" keywords make it possible to achieve any type based on the assignment at runtime, so when you query using "Where" the var entry becomes "IEnumerable" that is returned by Where, that's why you have to check for count.

Comment: `var` types are resolved at compile time, not at run time. `dynamic` types are resolved at run time.

Answer (score 0):

In VB

> Dim entry = myDB.Entries.Where(Function(e) e.Email = entry.Email).SingleOrDefault()
>
> If entry IsNot Nothing Then
>
> ' we have a value
>
> else
>
> ' we dont have a value
>
> End If