# var item throwing exception when tested against null

Tags: c#, exception

I am seeing some strange behaviour testing for null value against a var type using C#.NET

Here is some sample code.

```
//  locate user in cache

var user = GWUsers.Instance.Users.Where(u => u.EmailAddress == emailAddress).FirstOrDefault();

if (user != null)
{

}
```

When the user contains a null value an exception is thrown indicating that the "object reference is not set".

GWUsers is a singleton used to hold a list of users stored in an XML file. This very same piece of code is used throughout the application, but in this one instance, it throws an exception when evaluated against a null.

Any ideas why that  might be?

Appreciate any insight on this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure this has nothing to do with the `var` keyword or the `user` variable.

Comment: Are you sure that's where you're getting the exception?  Have you checked to make sure Users and/or Instance is not null?  Also, you should be able to do this:

`if (GWUsers.Instance.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress == emailAddress) != null) //...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230827/checking-for-null-value-in-c-var-with-linq-entity-framework

Comment: The stack trace will show you where the problem is. Also, you can just replace `Where` with `FirstOrDefault` instead of tacking it on the end.

Comment: Awesome @CharithJ, I just finished using a bunch of FirstOrDefault() methods when I really wanted .Any().  Just changed my own code.  ;o)

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I fond the problem. Although I find it odd, it did not appear anywhere else.

var user is instantiated from the User class. The User class has some operators defined for it as well. Such as the == and != operator. When we evaluate for null, the operator code is what's throwing the exception.  I discovered this after checking the stack trace.

Thank you for your replies.

Tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely the following could be the reasons:

- GWUsers.Instance.Users is null
- One of the instances in the list is null

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a null user element within Users, you could modify the LINQ statement to the following:

```
GWUsers.Instance.Users.Where(u => u != null && u.EmailAddress == u.mailAddress).FirstOrDefault();`
```

It would not help with `Users` being null, however.